# Google Classroom API create a link to the course

Tags: hyperlink, google-api, google-classroom

I am developing an agenda for my students. They are enrolled in different classes and have different courses in Google Classroom.

I am able to get the Classroom courses id, and get the grades. But I can not find information about how to link from my agenda to the course. Can I use the course id to create a link to the classroom course?

For example, if I get the courses list like this:

12012929120
12129399390
10101303003

Is there anyway to create a URL to go directly to that course? (For example: https://classroom.google.com/id/12012929120)

Or is any other way to retrieve my courses from the API and create links to my courses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the document, upon creating a classroom using [Method: courses.create](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/create) if the creation is successful the return value of this method is the classroom resource object which includes the `alternateLink`:

```
{
  "id": string,
  "name": string,
  "section": string,
  "descriptionHeading": string,
  "description": string,
  "room": string,
  "ownerId": string,
  "creationTime": string,
  "updateTime": string,
  "enrollmentCode": string,
  "courseState": enum(CourseState),
  "alternateLink": string,
  "teacherGroupEmail": string,
  "courseGroupEmail": string,
  "teacherFolder": {
    object(DriveFolder)
  },
  "courseMaterialSets": [
    {
      object(CourseMaterialSet)
    }
  ],
  "guardiansEnabled": boolean,
}
```

You can use the `alternateLink` to pass as a hyperlink for your classroom.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can form a url like:

https://classroom.google.com/c/

So if you id was 12012929120 the url might be:

https://classroom.google.com/c/MTIwMTI5MjkxMjA=

But I just know that via experimentation with my own course so I can't guarantee that will always work. I couldn't find any docs to answer the question definitively when I was trying to figure it out for myself.